# How to replace the 'cmd' alias in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

<kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> -> `cmd` -> <kbd>enter</kbd>

How to replace the *alias* of cmd?

I want to run [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) instead of default `cmd.exe`

Comment: add the location of the new cmd.exe to the front of your PATH variable?

Comment: @Trengot this don't work as long as it is called `cmd.exe` - I would have to rename it to something else

Comment: It should use the first matching executable it finds.

Comment: @Trengot well this makes sense. Unfortunately this don't work. Added my file-path to `PATH` as first one.

Comment: `PATH=cmderpath:normalpath` and also create a copy of `cmder` as `cmd.exe` on the same path as `cmder`

Comment: Try logging out and relogging in after you added the PATH. Windows does not reload the environment variables immediately.

Comment: @Vamsi nope, it does actually. Tried it with `cmder.exe` to proof it. Renamed it then to `cmd.exe` didn' t work.

@NuTTyX Well as I said before, I already did this? Not sure what you want to say tbh ;)

Comment: Since you have already added cmder path ahead of the `%PATH%` with cmder renamed to cmd, can you clarify what happens if you type cmd in Win+R. Does the original cmd.exe open ? If that is the case what happens if you type cmd in the now opened command prompt ?

Comment: Is `cmd` an alias? I thought it was a command.

Comment: @Vamsi Yes, it opens the ms cmd.exe. Interesting: win+r cmd = ms cmd, `cmd` in ms cmd.exe = cmder

Comment: Yep that is what I expected. A login/logoff should completely shadow out the original cmd.exe. `Win+R` uses both `%PATH%` and registry `APPPATH`. So a login/logoff is required to prioritize the new `%PATH%`. The new cmd prompt you opened reads the new environment variables on startup, so cmder == cmd works.

Comment: @Vamsi didn't work though.

Comment: I actually use cmder, so I went and investigated. I have written an answer below using the registry which works for me. So if that works accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows uses the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` to register full paths of applications which are visible from the Win+R shortcut. We can use the same behavior by creating an entry for cmd.exe here.

Use the portable program [AppPaths](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apppaths/) to safely write/edit the entry for cmd.exe to reflect the full path to cmder.exe and save. No reboot is required. You could manually write to the registry as well, but the app tests for errors before saving. Note that you will need admin rights either way.

EDIT For posterity, here are the steps for manually editing the registry as well.
Note that in the following, the alias `cmd` == `cmder` will be set for all users of the PC. If you only want the mapping for your user account, replace the registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in the following.

1. Run `regedit` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. You might need admin rights.
2. Create a new key with the name `cmd.exe` i.e. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\cmd.exe`
3. Modify the `Default` string in the newly created key to reflect the path to cmder.exe e.g. `C:\tools\cmder\cmder.exe`
4. In the `cmd.exe` key folder, create a new string called 'Path' and give it the value of the folder where cmder.exe is located. For the example path in step 3, this would be `C:\tools\cmder`. This step is not mandatory. It adds the directory to the PATH variable the cmder.exe inherits. This is useful if the directory contains any helper executables required by cmder.exe.

Comment: Well the app is crashing when I try to resize a column. Won't Investigate any more effort into this ;) But editing the registry works pretty good. This is actually a cool feature. Thank you very much! :) btw: you could edit your answer and explain how to add the registry entry (which key, where to put the .exe), for people who are reading this later..

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.  One small detail to note: be sure to remember ".exe" at the end of your alias.  Tried setting up an alias called "np" for Notepad++, but it didn't work until I made the alias np.exe.

Answer (score 0):

How I've achieved the same bypass of Windows' native applications:

1. Create a directory in root called "shortcuts" (C:\shortcuts assuming your root drive is C)

2. Add the path to the new directory to your PATH environment variable

3. Create a shortcut to cmder.exe, and rename the .lnk shortcut file to "cmd"

4. Place the shortcut into your new shortcuts directory

5. Windows+R> cmd

You would think that editing the registry would hold more sway than this workaround, but this is literally the way that I shortcut to anything, now.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? It don't work for me.

Comment: This has worked for me specifically in Windows 7 Home/Ultimate, and a multitude of Windows 98/XP versions. I have not tested in Windows 8, though.

Comment: I am pretty sure this will work only if you put the path to your shortcuts directory at *the beginning* of the PATH environment variable, because the directories in it are parsed one by one. It's pure speculation though.

Comment: I would make the assumption that the items added to the end, then, take precedence over the items added to the beginning. Overwriting existing associations, or something. It's definitely worth trying, though.

Comment: No the path is built upon the first seen values. You have to put it first if you want it to have precedence.