# How to associate batch files with another application rather than default cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to associate `.bat` files with another console emulator, like [cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/), so that when executing them they start up with my preferred program.

How to do this?

Comment: Similar question.
http://superuser.com/questions/810550/how-to-replace-the-cmd-alias-in-windows

Comment: Do you want to replace cmd for all purposes or just for running .bat files?  The similar question in metalcamp's comment covers the first case.  A different solution is needed for the second case.  Can you clarify?